# UNABLE TO INSTALL UPDATES "Not enought disk space"

Tags: 13.04, updates

I am unable to install updates. Get an error message saying "not enough free disk space" when there is plenty of disk space in the PC. I could send the screen shot if an e-mail address is provided.

I run 13.04

Please help.
Jay

Comment: Please upload your screenshots to an image hoster like [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and embed them in your question. The output of `df -h` would be helpful too.

Comment: A possibility is lack of space for a kernel update, which requires a good deal of extra disk space. But without the outputs it's hard to tell; please post the outputs of *df -h* and *apt-get upgrade*.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install bleachbit`

Comment: if you have free space still you get the message either your /boot partition is full or inodes are full.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was able to solve it with Ubuntu-Tweak.

Use your terminal and type or copy past.

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa

This will add the repository you need to get the app.

> sudo apt-get update

This will update the software list.

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak

This will install the app.

After you install it go to open dash and type "ubuntu tweak".

Once you run it go to janitor tab and select Apps , Personal and System

Then on the items on the right you can click on the boxes of what you want to clean. It will show you how much memory each item is using.

Then click the button clean on the bottom right of the screen.

This worked for me, hope it works for you.